# MFC : IHTMLElement how to remove an html element

Tags: html, mfc, visual-c++, tags

I have a dialog which has a web control... and with it I add elements using the put_innerHTML method of the class IHTMLElement. How do I delete elements though? I can't seem to find the method for it. Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do is incorporate javascript. Since this is a web control inside a form, using javascript is a lot easier.